# Change SCSS syntax to SASS syntax

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I want to write below CSS grid with SASS syntax. Currently it only works in SCSS syntax. Using SASS syntax I would like to reduce the [{] and [;] since SASS adds those characters automatically during/after compilation.

**SCSS syntax:**

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template:
    "logo-pic topbar-1"        80px
    "logo-pic topbar-2"        60px
    "navigation navigation"    60px
    "content content"          400px
    "bottom-bars bottom-bars"  80px
    / 250px 1fr;
}
```

What I have tried so far.

**SASS syntax:**

```
.wrapper
    display: grid
    grid-template:
    "logo-pic topbar-1"        80px
    "logo-pic topbar-2"        60px
    "navigation navigation"    60px
    "content content"          400px
    "bottom-bars bottom-bars"  80px
    / 250px 1fr
```

> Error: Expected expression. grid-template:

Comment: write everything in a single line?

Comment: @karthick I just tried that and it works. However, the visible structure of the CSS grid is really bad having everything in one line. If that is the only solution I have to stick to having the structure in a SCSS file.

Comment: there is a open issue regarding this https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216 don't see any recommended solutions. except the comment https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216#issuecomment-399026936

Comment: If you ever need to do that, simply go to SassMeister and let it convert it for you. https://www.sassmeister.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly why I never use any indention languages – they always fails on readability when you try to do anything a little out of the ordinary – leading to hacks to try bend the syntax.

Like this:

```
$a:       (    "logo-pic topbar-1"        80px)
$a: append($a, "logo-pic topbar-2"        60px)
$a: append($a, "navigation navigation"    60px)
$a: append($a, "content content"         400px)
$a: append($a, "bottom-bars bottom-bars"  80px)
$a: append($a, / 250px 1fr)

.wrapper
    display: grid
    grid-template: $a
```

... why (as you might have guessed) I would recommend you to **use SCSS** :)

PS. https://github.com/sass/sass/pull/2094